# MySQL incorrect timestamp value

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to insert datetime value '1970-01-01 00:00:01' in timestamp column but MySQL returned an error "Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' for column 'timestamp'"

```
CREATE TABLE TST_TABLE
(
  tst_column timestamp NULL
)

INSERT INTO TST_TABLE(tst_column) VALUES('1970-01-01 00:00:01');
```

I'm confused because MySQL documentation claims that lowest valid value for timestamp is '1970-01-01 00:00:01'. What's wrong and what is real lowest timestamp value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a timezone issue. Set the timezone to UTC before the insert, for example :

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
INSERT INTO TST_TABLE(tst_column) VALUES('1970-01-01 00:00:01');
```

An other option is to convert you timestamp to the UTC timezone using CONVERT_TZ. For exemple, if your timezone is `Europe/Paris` :

```
 INSERT INTO TST_TABLE(tst_column) VALUES(CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 00:00:01', 'Europe/Paris', 'UTC'));
```